# Classes for profiles

Tags: templates, document-classes, documentclass-writing

I'd like to create some handouts and documents with keywords for my daily presentations in school. As opposed to the tufte layouts theses documents are only one or two pages long.

The handout should give an overview over the facts I mentioned and explained during my presentation. For this I want to add lists of keysword (itemize and description) and some images. Adding a nice footer with the topic, the names and the date would also be necessary. All these task should be solved by a single class. I already know how to implement the footer and how to define some commands to manipulate it easily. To create a footer in a pleasant way I added this code to my handout.cls

```
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
%...
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\newcommand{\setnames}[1]{
    \def\names{#1}
}

\newcommand{\settopic}[1]{
    \def\topic{#1}
}

\newcommand{\footer}[1]{
    \fancyfoot[L]{\names, \topic, \today, \arabic{page}}
}
```

Now I can write in my main tex file something like:

```
\setnames{Nick Lehmann}
\settopic{Mein eigenes Handout}
\footer
```

Another part I already added is a command for creating a heading. Normally a handout is not divided into different section and has only one heading. So I added to handout.cls:

```
\newcommand{\heading}[1]{
    \centerline{\Large #1}
}
```

Because I would like to write my handouts in german, english (mostly british) or both I declared some options to configure the babel package.

```
\DeclareOption{german}{%
    \PassOptionsToPackage{ngerman}{babel}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \ClassWarning{handout}{German language selected}
}

\DeclareOption{british}{
    \PassOptionsToPackage{british}{babel}
    \ClassWarning{handout}{British language selected}
}
```

My section where I include the required packages look like

```
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{babel}
\RequirePackage[a4paper,vmargin={20mm,20mm},hmargin={30mm,30mm}]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{indentfirst}            
\RequirePackage{url}                    
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}               
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
```

Of course I pass other arguments to the article class and process the given options

```
\DeclareOption*{
    \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}
}

\ProcessOptions\relax
```

Does anybody has an idea to implement further features? I am very interested in an awesome way to present lists of keywords and descriptions for terms I explained in my presentation. Should I change my implementation? Did I forget something important?

Comment: Isn't this the wrong way? Why don't you start with a simple document, use scrartcl.cls and load all the packages you need. If you can't solve a problem, ask here. When your document has all the features, then you can think of putting nearly everthing before `\begin{document}`into your own package.

Comment: Yeah,  this could also be a way to achieve this. But I started with the idea to create a documentclass I can use very often or that I probably distribute. Don't get me wrong: I don't want to create a package but a documentclass.

Comment: Why? Why do you want a class? It seems odd to do this just for the sake of it...

Comment: It's not obvious at all what an answer here would be: could be too broad, could be opinion based, ...